# Using os.system to open a notepad file gives error 'System cannot find the path specified'

Tags: python

I am creating a text-file manager in Python, for which I store notepad files in a database that a user has created and open them on a button click. However, even though the files are in the same folder as that of the .py files, I get an error 'The system cannot find the file specified' when I open a file. Here's how I'm opening the file:

```
os.system("notepad "+filename+".txt")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If `notepad` is the name of the folder containing these files, you need to use slashes: `os.system("notepad\"+filename+".txt")`. Use double slash if you're on Windows.

Comment: Are these valid txt files? - Can you open them by yourself?

Comment: In order to understand better your problem, please detail where are those .txt files located, and where is the python code you're running (all those files should be in the same folder as your py file, and you only talked about those .txt files being in the same folder)

Comment: @VasilisG. no, I read "notepad filename.txt" to be the syntax to open a notepad file via os.system

Comment: @FilipMłynarski yes, I can

Comment: @LuanNaufal I'm sorry for being unclear, all python and .txt files are in the same folder.

Comment: I see you doesn't have absolute paths, are you sure you are running your python program when you are in it's folder?

Comment: What is `filename`? Did you use a raw string or escape the paths properly? You can't use relative path here because `notepad` may not have the same working directory.  Use absolute path to the file.

Comment: @SoumyaMukhija, this error you're getting I guess is still on python and not after opening notepad, where it asks if you'd like to create a new file with that name, right?
As a good practice, is always important to add the full path for the file / folder, in order to ensure your program is not running from elsewhere

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it's hard to see what error is. If you add the following directly before you can make sure the file is saved in the directory you think you're in: `file = open(filename + ".txt”,”w”); file.write(“Hello World”) ; file.close()`

Comment: it worked when I removed the .txt from the path specified. I don't know why, but it did.